# dbms_xmlgen.getxml statement throwing ORA-01704: string literal too long

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dbms-xmlgen, ora-01704

So I have this SQL statement that I am calling within the dbms_xmlgen.getxml function and I am receiving the error ORA-01704: string literal too long.

I believe the issues is that the SQL statement I am calling within the function is just too big.  I've seen lots of forum posts talking about a 4000 character limit and my statement is currently sitting at 4753 characters.  In fact my statement consists of two statements UNION'd together, if I take out one of them, which in essence halves my statement then it runs fine.

I cant make my statement 753 characters smaller, so is there anything I can do to get round this 4000 character limit?

If it helps I'm on Oracle 11g, release 11.2.0.2.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn your query into a view, and use that.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for this.  The same painfully obvious solution came to me during the weekend!